# inference variable T has incompatible bounds collectors.tolist in Function.identity

Tags: java-stream, flatmap

```
@Override
Public List<TranslationKey> getKeys(){
    return Stream.of(Arrays.stream(Message.values)), Arrays.stream(TranslationKeys.values()))
        .flatMap(Function.identity())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

getting error as inference variable T has incompatible bounds
what could be the issue, guide us. thanks

Comment: What is the type of `Message.values` and `TranslationKeys.values`?

Comment: There is a missing `)` in `.collect(Collectors.toList()` Besides that, it’s much simpler to use `return Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(Message.values)), Arrays.stream(TranslationKeys.values())).toList();` If you still have type inference issues, it might be because `Message.values` and `TranslationKeys.values()` have a non-trivial common super type. You can use an explicit type, i.e. `return Stream.<TranslationKeys>concat(Arrays.stream(Message.values)), Arrays.stream(TranslationKeys.values())).toList();` If the problem still persists, you have to provide more information.

Comment: Message and TranslationKeys  are enum type
@Holger tried your way but not working.

Comment: Well, then it’s *impossible* to make this work. If both are `enum` types, `Message` is not a  subtype of `TranslationKeys`. You are trying to construct a `List<TranslationKeys>` containing `Message` values (in addition to the `TranslationKeys` value).

Comment: Sorry for typo,     List<TranslationKey>     it's notp    TranslationKeys    
    TranslationKey     is an interface 
    TranslationKeys implement TranslationKey    
@Holger

Comment: And both, `Message` and `TranslationKeys`, implement the interface `TranslationKey`?

Comment: yes, you are right, both implements the same @Holger

Comment: See [here](https://ideone.com/WpIztP) for an example. `getKeysVariant1()` fixes your variant by inserting explicit types for your streams whereas `getKeysVariant2()` uses `concat` as suggested by me, which is already simpler in itself, but even works without explicit types. Note that my first comment used [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) instead of `collect(Collectors.toList())` which requires Java 16 or newer. This could be a reason why it didn’t work for you.